# CFLOOP with doubles - Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfloop

I am trying to use cfloop to loop form 0.0 to 5.0 but it takes out the decimal point and is looping from 0 to 5 instead.

This is my code

```
<select name="cweight">

    <option value="">---</option>

    <cfloop index = "cweight" from = "0.0" to = "5.0"> 
        <option value="#cweightid#">#cweight#</option>
    </cfloop>

</select>
```

I need the loop to go over 0.1,0.2,0.3 until it reaches 5.0.

What should I add to allow me to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

CF doesn't have "doubles" - numbers have decimal places when they need them.

To do what you want, use [NumberFormat](http://cfdocs.org/numberformat) with the mask set to 0.0 so that you always get a decimal place.

To increment by 0.1 at a time, simply set the [cfloop](http://cfdocs.org/cfloop-index-loop) step attribute.

```
<cfloop index="cweight" from="0" to="5" step="0.1"> 
    <option value="#cweight#">#NumberFormat( cweight ,'0.0' )#</option>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Good answer! Clear and concise.

Comment: Good answer for the first question but it does not really solve my issue. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: How does it not solve your issue? It loops perfectly from 0.1,.2, etc.?

Comment: it was giving 1.0 2.0 3.0 and then I deleted all of my code and just copied this one and now its fine. Thanks for questioning me @Busches or else I wouldn't test it again since it didn't give me an error.

Comment: You forgot the step="0.1" part.

Comment: The original question didn't indicate they wanted 0.1 steps at all - that was edited in after I had answered, so I also edited my answer to mention step, then 18 minutes later the comment was posted about the answer not working - I guess they hadn't refreshed the page to see the update...

Comment: I know. :) Just trying to explain the mix-up.

Comment: I strongly recommend avoiding decimals in your STEPs... CF behavior is unpredictable. http://brien-malone-web-dev.blogspot.com/2014/04/coldfusion-10-cfloop-bug-with-decimal.html